# if statement pattern

Tags: c#, if-statement

I don't understand this while loop structure. How does the ductCable get assigned? I see the logic test saying: "if type is IMMDuctCabe do stuff". But it looks like it is assigning that value at the same time.

```
items.Reset();
var item = items.Next();
while (item != null)
{
    if (item is IMMDuctCable ductCable)
    {
        var newDuctCable = new MMDuctCableClass();
        newDuctCable.cableID = ductCable.cableID; 
        ....
```

Comment: Read about the Type Pattern: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/is#type-pattern

Comment: The statement is equivalent to `if (item is IMMDuctCable) { var ductCable = item as IMMDuctCable; /* rest of if bloc */ `.  It's easier to type and to read - it's usually best to let the compiler do the work for you

Comment: If you want "if type is IMMDuctCabe do stuff" logic then the code should be `if (item is IMMDuctCable) {..}`. In your case you additionally provide a variable to fill with the value.